# Passing Data To An Embedded Table View (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

Trying to pass data to an embedded table view controller. I am able to pass the data to the view controller but not the embedded table view controller. I am assuming it has something to do with child/parent relationship... just not sure on the code to use for that relationship.

Here is what I have right now. The DealDetailTableViewController is embedded in a View Controller.

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
if (segue.identifier == "showDealDetails") {

    var detailScene = segue.destinationViewController as! DealDetailTableViewController

    if let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow() {
        let row = Int(indexPath.row)
        detailScene.dealObject = (objects?[row] as! PFObject)

    }

}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First,in the contain viewController,keep a variable

```
weak var embedvc:DealDetailTableViewController?
```

Then in prepare for segue

```
    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if (segue.identifier == "showDealDetails") {

        var detailScene = segue.destinationViewController as! DealDetailTableViewController

        self.embedvc = detailScene;

    }
}
```

Every time you pass data,you just need to

```
self.embedvc?.dealObject = ...//balabala
```